# Does this Optimization paper contain a mistake?

Tags: analysis, optimization, numerical-methods

I am reading the popular paper [Stochastic ADMM](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v28/ouyang13.pdf) by Hua Ouyang et. al. I have redone one of their calculations many times, and I keep coming up with a different answer. It is much more likely that I am incorrect rather than the paper, but could somebody please take a look? Thank you very much.

---

The problem is
\begin{align*} &\text{minimize } \ \  \theta_1(x) + \theta_2(y)\\
& \text{subject to } \ \  Ax + By = b, x \in \mathcal{X}
\end{align*}

The augmented Lagrangian, as given on page 3 (bottom left) is
$$L_{\beta}(x, y, \lambda) = \theta_1(x) + \theta_2(y) + \lambda^T(Ax + By - b) + \frac \beta 2 ||Ax + By - b||^2.$$

Shortly after this, it claimed that the x-subproblem $$\arg \min_{x \in \mathcal{X}} L_{\beta}(x, y^k, \lambda^k)$$ (where $y^k, \lambda^k$ are the $k^{th}$ iterates) can be written as
$$\arg \min_{x \in \mathcal{X}} \theta_1(x) + \frac \beta 2||Ax + By^k - b - \frac 1 \beta \lambda^k ||^2.$$
In my calculations, I keep getting $+ \frac 1 \beta \lambda^k$ instead of $- \frac 1 \beta \lambda^k$.

**My Calculation**

Here, I took away the superscript $k$ and the subscript $x \in \mathcal{X}$ for convenience. I also add and neglect constant terms without explicitly saying so.

\begin{align*}
\arg \min_x L_{\beta}(x, y, \lambda) &= \arg \min _x \theta_1(x) + \theta_2(y) + \lambda^T (Ax + By - b) + \frac \beta 2||Ax+By-b||^2\\
&= \arg \min_x \theta_1(x) + \lambda^TAx + \frac \beta 2(x^TA^TAx + 2y^TB^TAx - 2b^TAx )\\
&= \arg \min_x \theta_1(x) + \frac \beta 2(x^TA^TAx + 2(By - b + \frac 1 \beta \lambda)^TAx)\\
&= \arg \min_x \theta_1(x) + \frac \beta 2(x^TA^TAx + 2v^TAx)\\
&= \arg \min_x \theta_1(x) + \frac \beta 2(x^TA^TAx + 2v^TAx + v^Tv)\\
&= \arg \min_x \theta_1(x) + \frac \beta 2||Ax + v||^2\\
&= \arg \min_x \theta_1(x) + \frac \beta 2||Ax + By - b + \frac 1 \beta \lambda ||^2
\end{align*}

Comment: You are right, $λ^Tu+\fracβ2\|u\|^2=\fracβ2\|u+\fracλβ\|^2-\frac{\|λ\|^2}{2β}$. The sign of $λ$ is not important, so both versions could be correct. Now you have to check if that is a single transcription or consistency error, or if the opposing conventions are somewhere used at the same time to derive a then wrong result.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thanks for your comment. Could you explain, why would the sign of $\lambda$ not be important?

Comment: I should have said the sign convention is not important. For an equality constraint, the multiplier $λ$ is unconstrained. It makes no difference in the Lagrangian if the term is added or subtracted. For the actual values of the multiplier in the KKT system the sign is of course important. It could be that the paper was started in one form, then the other form was found a little more something, but the change was not made rigorously enough.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Ohh you mean that for this calculation, they assumed the Lagrangian is $$L_{\beta}(x, y, \lambda) = \theta_1(x) + \theta_2(y) - \lambda^T(Ax + By - b) + \frac \beta 2 ||Ax + By - b||^2.$$I see. Thanks!